# how to specify form name in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5

Basically, i am trying to validate form used in "Laravel" where i need to know the name of the form.

For instance in HTML we can simply write:

```
  <form action="" name="registration">
```

From the above code we can get the name of the form whereas in "Laravel" I cannot specify the form name as such.

Comment: Are you using Laravel's `Form::open()` ?

Comment: post whatever you tried.

Comment: I havent tried anything. Yes, i am using Form::open()

Comment: please mention your form code

Comment: {!! Form::open( array( 'route' => array(getLang(). '.admin.package.update', $package->id), 'method' => 'PATCH', 'files'=>true)) !!}

Comment: {!! Form::submit('Update Package', array('class' => 'btn btn-success' 'id' => 'validator')) !!}

Comment: For above code check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408231/how-to-specify-form-name-in-laravel/42408719#42408719)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'your route url', 'name' => 'registration')) !!}
```

You will get sample contact form [here](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/09/creating-a-contact-form-in-laravel-5-using-the-form-request-feature/) using laravel form and html tags

Give it a try, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for laravel form syntax:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

You can provide form name like this in the form syntax:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'some route url','id'=>"some_form_id",'name'=>"form name")) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

@SnowmanOnFire : For your revised comment, following will work

```
{!! Form::open( array( 'route' => array(getLang(). '.admin.package.update', $package->id), 'method' => 'PATCH', 'files'=>true, 'name' => 'registration')) !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

Above answers are correct as below you can achieve it.

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'your_action_url','name' => 'registration', 'class'=>'your classes']) }}
```

Add more attributes of form as you want.